# Any errors of these two sentences?

Tags: differences

> My father is my hero.
>
> My hero is my father.

Any difference between or errors in these two sentences?

Comment: what are your thoughts?

Comment: Do these two sentences same meaning?

Comment: Any grammar errors in these two sentences?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first sentence can be taken to imply you have lots of heroes, of which your father is one.

The second sentence implies your father is your only hero.

Both are grammatically okay.

Answer (score 0):

Neither is erroneous and both can be used for any practical situation.

I would say the real difference is simply that the first describes your father, while the second describes your hero.

Both imply that you have only one hero because both use the phrase *My hero*. To imply that you have more than one hero you would say:

> My father is one of my heroes

or

> One of my heroes is my father

Strictly speaking *My father is my hero* prevents you from having other heroes, but I agree with JohnMark Perry that in reality no-one will mind if you say *And so is my Mother*